# How to parse ip address from /proc/PID/net/tcp and /proc/PID/net/tcp6 files in Java?

Tags: java, linux

Here are some output from /proc/PID/net/tcp6 file:

```
  sl  local_address                         remote_address                        st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt   uid  timeout inode
   0: 0000000000000000FFFF00000F02000A:BDC7 0000000000000000FFFF00002ACD3AD8:01BB 08 00000000:00000001 00:00000000 00000000 10007        0 130895 1 00000000 29 4 14 10 -1
```

Comment: This is super vague. See [mcve] and [ask] about how to ask a question.